# Unable to load environement variables when running the server with typescript and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, dotenv

I create a node.js server using typescript, the project structure is like this:

```
|--node_modules
|--server
   .env
   |-- build
   |-- src
       |-- database
       |-- controllers
       |-- models
       |-- routes
       |-- utils
       |-- app.ts
       |-- server.ts
```

app.ts:

```
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import { config } from "dotenv";
import express, { Express } from "express";
config({ path: __dirname + "../.env" });
import db from "./database/config";

db.once("open", () => logger.info("connected to the database"));

// checks if connection with the database is successful
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));

const app: Express = express();
.
.
.
```

database/config.ts:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { logger } from "../utils/log";

const url = process.env.MONGODB_DEV_HOST;

mongoose
  .connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
  })
  .then(() => {
    logger.info("Database starts successfully");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    logger.error("Error when starting database: \n", error);
  });

const db = mongoose.connection;

export default db;
```

.env:

```
MONGODB_DEV_HOST=mongodb://localhost:27017/db
```

When I run my server, I got an error due to the `mongodb`server because the url is undefined.
I put the `.env`file in the root of the project. Do I miss something in my configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. But in my case, TSLint was catching an error `No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3,..` as the mongodb host URL was `undefined`.

I think it is due to the global.d.ts declaration for the `.env` in which the `ProcessEnv` interface return `string` or `undefined`. 
This can be found here `node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts`

#### The original ProcessEnv from global.d.ts

```
interface ProcessEnv {
  [key: string]: string | undefined;
}
```

#### How I solved the issue

I solve this problem by creating a config file inside my `src` folder. You can actually put it anywhere.

And the config file forces the `process.env` to return `string` only and I am exporting my variables as constant to be directly used inside my controllers, middlewares, etc.

Here is how my config file looks like:

```
import { config } from 'dotenv';

config();

export const {
  MONGODB_DEV_HOST,
  JWT_SECRET,
  FACEBOOK_API_KEY,
} = process.env as {
  [key: string]: string;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
import {} from 'dotenv/config'
```

Why is this happening? . Basically, an import statement is executed in a depth first search traversal, before your code runs, and at that point it sets you env variable, which is of course undefined at that point, and guess when your config invocation is called? At **runtime**. That happens because `import` statements are very different from `require` statements by design. Calling the config directly from an import statement at the top of the file overcomes this problem.

Comment: Instead of specifying an empty import list, import the dependency as `import 'dotenv/config';`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using typescript, you should import the **dotenv** and **invoke** it at the top before importing express. If you import it later you might have problems when you use **process.env.<ENV_VARIABLE>** in functions or variables you define in seperate files and import to your main files. An example is as follows:

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config({debug: true});
import express, { Express, Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
```